# user validation for admin presence

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to write a validation for `User`that ensures that `company.users.where(admin: true).size >= 1` that way if there is only one admin in the company, she can't revoke her admin access and the company is stuck without any admin.

I'm thinking I need to write a validation that checks if the user is changing the `admin` to false and if the size of user admins is equal to 1 than give an error message.

This is what I have so far, but I'm not sure how to trigger this with the right type of validation.

```
  def company_have_one_admin_present
    errors.add(:admin, 'must have one admin') if 1 == company.users.where(admin: true).size
  end
```

Comment: What happens with new companies? Always the first user created will be an admin? Are there users without a company?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this to your model, I haven't tested it but I think you can do something like this:

```
   validate :company_have_one_admin_present, on: :update

    def company_have_one_admin_present
      admins = company.users.where(admin: true)
      if !admin? && admins.size == 1 && admins.find_by(id: id)
        errors.add(:admin, "at least one admin required")
      end
    end
```

This validation only happens if the user is not a new record `on: :update` ,  and that he is currently set to not be an admin `!admin?`, but in the database he is actually set as an admin (and the only one for the company) `admins.size == 1 && admins.find_by(id: id)`

Comment: I added on update to the validation, and that made it work

Comment: right, by using `on: :update` there's no longer a need for `persisted?`. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest this solution

```
class User

  validate :company_have_one_admin_present

  def company_have_one_admin_present
    if persisted? &&
       (company.users.where(admin: true).count == 1) &&
       (admin_changed? && admin == false)
      errors.add(:admin, 'must have at least one admin') 
    end
  end
end
```

Explanation :

1. `company.users.where(admin: true).count == 1` because count will not
   initialize all the users, saving time and memory.
2. `admin_changed? && admin == false` means that if you are changing your admin to false, your admin was set to true and therefore you were the only admin ! So whoops no you can't change your admin status !

Comment: I like your solution, I didn't know about the `_changed?` but I think you need to check that he was the previous admin of the company explicitly, because maybe he's currently changing the company also, and the new company had a single (different) admin.

Comment: Good catch ! But then `admins.find_by(id: id)`doesn't work because self hasn't saved yet and you are querying on its old/previous company. No? So we should also check if company has changed I guess...

Comment: No, if the company is changed as well, then when you do `admins.find_by(id: id)`,  you're querying the new company, and it should return nil.